# How to make multiple conditions on python next cord

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

So I want to make a command where for only a few certain people it says something specific and for the others that aren't specified on the code, it will just say a normal thing.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == 1:
        await ctx.reply('Hello Person 1')
    if ctx.author.id == 2:
        await ctx.reply("Hello Person 2")
    if not ctx.author.id == 1 and 2:
        await ctx.reply ("Hello")
```

Something like the code above, which I did in fact try, but it will not count the second condition on line 7. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ctx.author.id == 1 and 2
```

This is `True` if `ctx.author.id == 1` and `2`. Since `2` is not `0` and thus always truthy, the entire expression is always `True` if `ctx.author.id == 1`

The `not` then reverses that, so the entire expression as you used it is always `True` if `ctx.author.id != 1`

What you meant was:

```
not (ctx.author.id == 1 or ctx.author.id == 2)
```

Or:

```
ctx.author.id != 1 and ctx.author.id != 2
```

Or:

```
ctx.author.id not in [1, 2]
```

Even this does not work:

```
not ctx.author.id == (1 and 2)
```

Because that just computes `1 and 2` (neither is `0`, so the result is a truthy `2`). Not what you are after, since that just ends up testing if `ctx.author.id` equals 2 (confusingly).

Answer (score -1):

While Python may look like English, it is in fact *not* English. In English, I can say, "today is hot and sunny", and it means that today is hot **and** today is sunny. However, computers don't work like that. They cannot infer things that way, and so you need to be explicit, such as:

```py
if not (ctx.author.id == 1 and ctx.author.id == 2):
    await ctx.reply ("Hello")
```